# Add Page Categories to Wordpress admin menu

Tags: wordpress

I am using the **Post Tags and Categories for Pages** plugin for Wordpress 4 which allows me to sort pages into separate category.

I would like to add the page categories to the Wordpress admin menu but am struggling to find any tutorials covering this, does anyone know of a method for doing this or a plugin which can be used.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a plugin called "[Custom post type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)", it will allow you to create custom post types (kind of like pages ) and taxonomies (kind of categories).

Here is a great video tutorial for that, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpeTZ3ghjtY

Comment: Needs to be pages for what I am building. Thanks though

Comment: If you just need categories for pages, You can use this plugin to create a custom taxonomy for pages. Pages by default dont have categories, so you will have to create a taxonomy. Taxonomy is another name for custom category.